# How to get all liked image of user of instagram?

Tags: instagram

Instagram only returns latest 300 liked images via instagram API. Is there any way to get all liked images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram limits the number of images returned for instagram likes and feed API, its not really 300 always, it can be less than that. No other way to get all.

Comment: Thanks @krisrak for your Response. Does instagram provide all liked photo by paying or some other means? Do you have any idea?